# find number that starts with

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry about this, but my knowledge of xsl is not fantastic. 
I need to find a number between 4500000000 and 4500999999, but as it comes from an external source I can't specify the name of the attribute.
I have this to search inside the node in Addenda, but not working...

```
<xsl:template name="Pruebas">
<xsl:for-each select="cfdi:Addenda/node()">
   <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
     <xsl:if test="starts-with(string(.),'4500')">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each> 
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you post a xml example?

Comment: Do you want to look only in attributes for this value?

Comment: No, I want to look in all the nodes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:if test="number(.) < 4500999999 and number(.) > 4500000000">`

Will this work? I'm on my phone so i can't test it.

Comment: If you do this, use `&lt;` or  `&gt;`  instead of `< >`.